# How to set the color of tmux copy-mode's highlight?

Tags: tmux

I recently changed my tmux colorscheme and succeeded in setting the colors for the statusbar and clock-mode as well as for the tmux command line.

However, I failed to find an option on how to set the highlighting color of the copy-mode.

Is there such an option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tmux uses the window option `mode-style` for the copy-mode highlighting.

You can use `set-window-option -g mode-style [your style]` like you would with any other color setting.

`mode-style` is used in a handful of other places, such as the selection highlighting when using the `choose-window` and `choose-session` commands.

Comment: is it possible to set the colors to be reverted as they are in vim visual mode?

Comment: @alexzander something like `set -g mode-style "fg=default,bg=default,reverse"` should work (works for me).

Comment: hmm. thanks a lot.